# Get attr_reader, writer, or accessor oustide of the class

Tags: ruby, methods, metaprogramming

I'm currently doing some metaprogramming with ruby, and I'm trying to isolate the methods of class (that class is in another file, that I get by a require). I can get all the methods, thanks to klass.public_instance_methods(false), but I in the sametime, the array given also have all the attributes of the class. How could I isolate them ? In others related questions on SO, they suggest to use klass.instance_variables but when I do that, it only returns an empty array.

I can't seem to wrap my head around that one. I don't understand why there isn't a method specifically for that already...

For example:

I have in a file this class :

```
class T
    attr_reader:a
    def initialize(a)
        @a = a
    end
    def meth
        #code here
    end
end
```

And, in another file, i have

```
require_relative 'T.rb'
class meta
   def initialize
       methods = T.public_instance_methods(false) #=> here methods = [:a,:meth] but I would want only to have [:meth]
       #rest of code
   end
end
```

Comment: can you explain with an example?

Comment: @VishalTajPM I added an example

Comment: "the array given also have all the attributes of the class" - what attributes? The accessors? `attr_accessor` is a simple macro that defines two instance methods. No more, no less. There's nothing special about those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For class defined like this:

```
class Klass
    attr_accessor :variable
    def initialize(variable)
        @variable = variable
    end

    def method
    end
end
```

you can find public non-attr instance methods using `public_instance_methods` and `instance_variables` methods.

```
public_instance_methods  = Klass.public_instance_methods(false)
#  [:method, :variable, :variable=]

instance_variables = Klass.new(nil).instance_variables
# [:@variable]

getters_and_setters = instance_variables
                        .map(&:to_s)
                        .map{|v| v[1..-1] }
                        .flat_map {|v| [v, v + '=']}
                        .map(&:to_sym)
# [:variable, :variable=]

without_attr = public_instance_methods - getters_and_setters
# [:method]
```

Comment: Yes ! Thank you so much, it's exactly that ! I missed the instanciation of the class, that's why it didn't work earlier.

Comment: @Lusheez I'm glad I could help. Also, I updated my answer because original code worked for getters only - it didn't subtract `<name>=` methods from `public_instance_methods` array

Comment: This only works if `initialize` creates all the instance variables. In general instance variables can be defined at any time so it's impossible to distinguish between a non-attribute method and a getter whose variable has yet to be defined.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. Ruby's "attributes" are completely normal methods. There is no way to distinguish them from other methods. For example, these two classes are completely indistinguishable:

```
class Foo
   attr_reader :bar
end

class Foo
   def bar
     @bar
   end
end
```

You can try to be clever and filter them out based on instance variables, but that is dangerous:

```
class Foo
  # can filter this out using @bar
  attr_writer :bar
  def initialize
    @bar = []
  end
end

class Foo
  def initialize
    @bar = []
  end

  # this looks the same as above, but isn't a normal attribute!
  def bar= x
    @bar = x.to_a
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, although for my precise purpose the solution proposed by Maciej fits really well !